# How to store map data in array with Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make an app about health blog with Flutter. I want to store some data with arrays that contain map data. Although I can manually perform this on the Firestore, I'm getting some errors in coding.

[Here is Firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC2hC.png)

Here is the code which I try to add map data to the array.

```
    Future<bool> updateUserCases(String userId, Map newCase) async {
    await _firestoreDB.collection("users").doc(userId).update({
      "userCases" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([newCase])
    });
    return true;
  }
```

I can add my map data to Firestore, but when I try to add it to the array, I get this error.

> E/flutter (10661): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with set() and update()

And this is my "Case Model" which I want to add into the array

```
    class CaseModel {
  final String caseId;
  final String caseTitle;
  final String caseBody;
  final Map caseOwner;
  Timestamp caseDate;
  bool caseSolve;
  List<String> casePhotos;
  String caseTag;

  CaseModel(
      {@required this.caseOwner,
      this.caseId,
      this.caseTitle,
      this.caseBody,
      this.caseDate,
      this.caseTag});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "case_id": caseId,
      "case_title": caseTitle,
      "case_body": caseBody,
      "case_owner": caseOwner,
      "case_date": caseDate ?? FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      "case_solve": caseSolve,
      "case_photos": casePhotos,
      "case_tag": caseTag,
    };
  }
```

Could you help if there is a way I can fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the value of `newCase`.  Also, are you using `serverTimestamp()` anywhere in this code?

Comment: The problem has been updated as you say.

Comment: By the way I use `serverTimestamp()` in `CaseModel`  but its working correctly when i set `newCase` into Firestore document.